# Getting capture date of heic image

Tags: c++, hevc, lib, heif

I am using the nokiatech heif api (github.com/nokiatech/heif) to process heic files produced by the IOS betas.

I am able to get the tiles and metadata like rotation and dimensions, but I am unable to locate the capture date of the image. I found some timestamp functions but they complain about "Forced FPS not set for meta context" which leads me to think these functions are related to tracks and not items.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

So there is a typo in the documentation for getReferencedToItemListByType (and getReferencedFromItemListByType), it says it takes "cdcs" as a referenceType parameter. It is ofcource "cdsc" (Content Describe).

So to get the metadata blob from a stil image as of now you can do the following:

```
reader.getItemListByType(contextId, "grid", gridItemIds);
ImageFileReaderInterface::IdVector cdscItemIds;
reader.getReferencedToItemListByType(contextId, gridItemIds.at(0), "cdsc", cdscItemIds);
ImageFileReaderInterface::DataVector data;
reader.getItemData(contextId, cdscItemIds.at(0), data);
```

Then you need to decode the exif. You can easily use Exiftool cli or an api like exiv2.